Betti Numbers over Z/2
My understanding is that if we have some nth-homology group H_n(X), then the rank of H_n(X) is the Betti number B_n. This is like saying the Betti number is the same as the number of linearly independent generators of H_n(X).
I am under the impression that over Z/2, dim(H_n(X)) = B_n, and that intuitively we're saying H_n(X) has a basis of 'holes' at a given dimension in the simplicial complex, and B_n is then counting how many 'holes' there are.
Is this correct? If so, could somebody provide an intuitive reason as to why this is the case. And why, then, does the same idea not hold over different rings? If I'm incorrect, could somebody put me on the right track? I'm struggling to find any clear resources on this, so the help would be appreciated! Thanks!

Please use MathJax. Here is a
tutorial.

The following is implied by your title but perhaps contradicted by the phrasing of your question: note that the Betti numbers depend on the coefficient ring, and so perhaps it would be better to write $\beta_n^{R}$, for example, for the rank of $H_n(X;R)$. In particular, the mod $2$ Betti numbers are not always the same as the integral ones, and the projective plane provides a nice example of this: we have

$\beta_2^{\mathbb{F}_2} = \beta_1^{\mathbb{F}_2} = 1$
$\beta_2^{\mathbb{Z}} = \beta_1^{\mathbb{Z}} = 0$
$\beta_2^{\mathbb{Q}} = \beta_1^{\mathbb{Q}} = 0$

When it comes to counting holes, how much sense does it make to say that the projective plane has a mod 2 hole but not an integral hole? I would say that counting holes is a fine way to discuss homology when you first encounter it, but it quickly becomes less useful, and you should just view homology groups as presenting some information about the space without a simple geometric interpretation.

One key thing is that $\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z$ is a field; a consequence of that is that $H_i(X, \mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z)$ ends up a vector space. There's nothing like the weirdness you get with integer coefficients, like $H_i(X, \mathbb Z) = \mathbb Z \oplus \mathbb Z/3\mathbb Z \oplus \mathbb Z/5\mathbb Z$. That "weirdness" can denote characteristics that are stranger than what you might imagine shapes can look like, but they're (somewhat) masked when you take mod-2 homology.
As for "counting holes," you might want to ask "does the projective plane have a 1-dimensional hole or not?" With mod-2 coefficients, all three homology groups are $\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z$. You have to decide whether this matches your intuition about holes and about the projective plane before you can say whether those mod-2 groups really "count holes".
